# How can I train a model to detect multiple values for the same key in one page?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am using Forms Recognizer v2, specifically the Sample Labeling tool, to build and train a model that aims to parse information from [packing lists](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/packing-list.html). After labeling more than 5 documents, I train the model and then pass one of the documents to perform a prediction. However, the model can only predict one value for each key/tag, even though during the labeling process, I assigned multiple values to each tag. Is this a limitation in the current version of the tool, or am I missing something?

Best regards,
João Amaro

Answer (score 0):

We can handle multiple value text lines if they are very close to each other (e.g., an address that runs multiple lines next to each other). However, if the multiple values are spread in different places, we suggest you use different keys for them.

Comment: Greetings @ChaZ, I see. Unfortunately, I have no _a priori_ knowledge of the number of items in each packing list, so I can only try creating keys for the maximum number of tags. If it works, I'll accept the answer

Comment: Are you handling a table with multiple line items, or your packing list is just spread across the document?

Comment: For this particular supplier, my packing lists have multiple tables across the document, and each table might have one or more items.

Comment: Table items are not handled by labeling. The returned analyze result shall include tables detected from the form, with cell structure. For now please use that to parse items in tables.